# rename GUI file and callbacks

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I've renamed My "*.m" and "*.fig" on the same name, in my "*.m" i've replaced occurrence of previous name with the new one.

Is any efficient way to rename a simple GUI file without renaming all the callbacks (in the property panel) on the "*.fig" file ?

Have so many callbacks and button that it's really fastidious to make it manually.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I usually open the .fig file in GUIDE, save it with an other name, and with default options a new .m file should be created with the new name.
Callbacks should also be renamed automatically if you didn't change their '%auto' option in GUIDE.
Hope that helps !